# Find the IMDb Rating of those movies whose IMDb Rating is above average in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a movie table inside my Movie_Info database which contains Movie_Name, Movie_ID, IMDB_Rating, Genre, etc fields.

Now I need to **find the name, IMDb rating, and genre of those movies whose IMDb Rating is above average.**

my approach:

```
SELECT
        Movie_name
        ,IMDB_Rating
        ,Genre
    FROM
        movie
    HAVING
        IMDB_Rating >= AVG (IMDB_Rating)
```

But it gives the 1st entry/row of the table, not the correct one. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Movie_name
     , IMDB_Rating
     , Genre
  FROM movie
 WHERE IMDB_Rating > ( SELECT AVG(IMDB_Rating)
                         FROM movie 
                     )
```